# Spring mvc custom date format based on locale

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Here's my controller:

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(final WebDataBinder binder) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, new Locale("lt"));
    dateFormat.setLenient(true);
    CustomDateEditor editor = new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, editor);
}
```

When I submit my form I get an error saying :

> Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required
>   type java.util.Date for property dateFrom; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type java.lang.String to type java.util.Date for value
>   2014-02-20; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution doesn't work because of `lt` locale has a datepattern like `yy.M.d`

Your dateFrom has value 2014-02-20, and your `DateFormat` is trying to convert using the below datepattern.

Try to put into your dateFrom parameter something like 14.02.20 and should work.

Comment: It's lt - lithuanian locale, not italian.

Answer (score 0):

Italy default Date format for Short is dd/mm/yyyy . refer [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country) . if you submit your input as 20/02/2014 , you will be good.

You can also test, like this.

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.ITALY);
    dateFormat.setLenient(true);
    CustomDateEditor editor = new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true);
    editor.setAsText("20/02/2012");
```

or use the SimpleDateFormat and specify your format.